# Any workaround for the table decorators bug?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there any work around for this bug?

https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=160&q=label%3DBugs

Currently I manually run an expensive full load once a day and override the partial data I loaded using the table decorators. Is there any idea of how to go around this until the bug is accepted and fixed?

Bug was allegedly fixed, but problem still exists... workaround will be highly appriciated.

Comment: I would also really appreciate to have an update soon on this problem that is affecting us.

Comment: @<N.N.> did you have news regarding this issue?

Comment: Not yet. however, in the past 3 days i don't see the symptoms anymore. I wish BQ guys could update if this was an incidents, or a problem that we should expect to reoccur.